# How to create a table using another table metadata(structure, primary_key, foreign key, indexes, tablespace all) which is in another db server?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have used this following script but it cannot copy the primary key constraints, indexes and others. How can i get all the constrains too while creating tables from another server to different server?

```
declare
cursor rec is 
        select * from all_objects@MAINDB
        where owner='MAINDB' and object_type in 
        ('TABLE') AND OBJECT_NAME IN ('TBL1','TBL2');
begin
  for i in rec loop
     begin 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('create '||i.object_type||' '||i.object_name||' as select * from '||i.object_name||'@MAINDB');
     execute immediate 'create '||i.object_type||' '||i.object_name||' as select * from '||i.object_name||'@MAINDB';
     end;
   end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: It would probably be simpler to use `dbms_metadata` to extract all of the DDL from the remote database - assuming the DB link is connected as the owner - and execute that locally. And then populate it with the data at the end. But, if there are *foreign* key constraints then this will get messy. Why not just use data pump to export and import the tables (with expdp/impdp), or import (impdp) [using a network link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/datapump-import-utility.html#GUID-0871E56B-07EB-43B3-91DA-D1F457CF6182)?

Comment: Can you give me a example for dbms_metadata uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the Oracle documentation [dbms_metadata](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_METADATA.html).
It was primarily designed, however, for scripting DDL of local objects. To use it against a remote database over a link, you have to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to work with the *remote* `dbms_metadata` package (not the local one) and you must use `fetch_ddl_text` rather than the simpler `fetch_ddl`. Here's a function from one of my programs that does this that can serve as an example. Obviously your needs would adapt this and change as necessary:

```
   /*
   ** FUNCTION: [PL_LOAD_DDLS_BY_CLASS].FL_GET_REMOTE_DDLS
   **
   ** Uses dbms_metadata to obtain remote DDL. Normally dbms_metadata is not supported over a database link, but it can be made to work
   ** by using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to execute the remote package and by using fetch_ddl_text rather than fetch_ddl.
   */
   FUNCTION fl_get_remote_ddls(var_link_name IN varchar2,
                               in_owner IN varchar2,
                               in_object_name IN varchar2,
                               in_object_Type IN varchar2)
     RETURN sys.ku$_ddls
   AS
      var_ddls sys.ku$_ddls := sys.ku$_ddls();
      var_handle number;
      var_transform number;
      var_partial number;
      var_buffer varchar2(32767 BYTE);
      var_clob clob;
      no_more_ddls Boolean;
   BEGIN
     /*
     ** Create a dbms_metadata session and set filters and transforms to obtain DDL for a given object
     */
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :1 := dbms_metadata.open@'||var_link_name||'(:2); END;' USING OUT var_handle, IN in_object_type;

     IF in_object_type = 'OBJECT_GRANT'
     THEN
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN dbms_metadata.set_filter@'||var_link_name||'(:1, ''BASE_OBJECT_SCHEMA'', :2); END;' USING IN var_handle, IN in_owner;
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN dbms_metadata.set_filter@'||var_link_name||'(:1, ''BASE_OBJECT_NAME'', :2); END;' USING IN var_handle, IN in_object_name;
     ELSE
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN dbms_metadata.set_filter@'||var_link_name||'(:1, ''SCHEMA'', :2); END;' USING IN var_handle, IN in_owner;
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN dbms_metadata.set_filter@'||var_link_name||'(:1, ''NAME'', :2); END;' USING IN var_handle, IN in_object_name;
     END IF;

     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :1 := dbms_metadata.add_transform@'||var_link_name||'(:2, ''DDL''); END;' USING OUT var_transform, IN var_handle;

     /*
     ** Omit storage clauses, as they are not important
     */
     IF in_object_Type IN ('INDEX','CONSTRAINT','CLUSTER','TABLE')
     THEN
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN dbms_metadata.set_transform_param@'||var_link_name||'(:1, ''STORAGE'', FALSE); END;' USING IN var_transform;
     END IF;

     /*
     ** Do not include constraints in table DDL. We want to handle them separately so changes in constraints do not require a table recreate.
     */
     IF in_object_type = 'TABLE'
     THEN
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN dbms_metadata.set_transform_param@'||var_link_name||'(:1, ''REF_CONSTRAINTS'', FALSE); END;' USING IN var_transform;
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN dbms_metadata.set_transform_param@'||var_link_name||'(:1, ''CONSTRAINTS'', FALSE); END;' USING IN var_transform;
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN dbms_metadata.set_transform_param@'||var_link_name||'(:1, ''SIZE_BYTE_KEYWORD'', TRUE); END;' USING IN var_transform;
     END IF;

     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN dbms_metadata.set_transform_param@'||var_link_name||'(:1, ''EMIT_SCHEMA'', FALSE); END;' USING IN var_transform;

     no_more_ddls := FALSE;

     WHILE NOT no_more_ddls
     LOOP
       dbms_lob.createtemporary(var_clob,TRUE);
       dbms_lob.open(var_clob,dbms_lob.lob_readwrite);

       var_partial := 1;

       /*
       ** The fetch_ddl_text function returns what would be a CLOB in multiple pieces of varchar2. The second parameter is an OUT parm called partial,
       ** and while it is positive there is still more text to be retrieved. When it returns 0, the entire original CLOB for a DDL statement has been
       ** fully retrieved. But there may be more statements, so we must keep fetching. When partial returns NULL there are no more statements left. As
       ** we pull each piece across we reassemble the CLOBs on our local end using dbms_lob.writeappend.
       */
       WHILE var_partial > 0
       LOOP
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :1 := dbms_metadata.fetch_ddl_text@'||var_link_name||'(:2,:3); END;' USING OUT var_buffer, IN var_handle, OUT var_partial;

         IF var_partial IS NULL
         THEN
           no_more_ddls := TRUE;
         ELSE
           IF LENGTH(var_buffer) > 0
           THEN
             dbms_lob.writeappend(var_clob,LENGTH(var_buffer),var_buffer);
           END IF;
         END IF;
       END LOOP;

       /*
       ** Add the reassembled CLOB to the same array type that dbms_metadata.fetch_ddl would have returned.
       */
       IF var_partial = 0 AND dbms_lob.getlength(var_clob) > 0
       THEN
         var_ddls.EXTEND;
         /*
         ** Forcibly strip out any lingering schema names still prefixed to objects. The EMIT_SCHEMA transform does not work in all cases.
         */
         var_ddls(var_ddls.LAST) := sys.ku$_ddl(var_clob,NULL);
       END IF;

       dbms_lob.close(var_clob);
       dbms_lob.freetemporary(var_clob);
     END LOOP;

     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN dbms_metadata.close@'||var_link_name||'(:1); END;' USING IN var_handle;

     RETURN var_ddls;
   END fl_get_remote_ddls;
```

As you can see, it is rather complex, though the function above was written to pull almost any kind of object. Your needs may be simpler. Again, consult the documentation to tailor something that fits your situation.